# In VSTS Wiki - Create A New Page with a Link - Like OneNote

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, onenote

In OneNote, I can create a new page and [automatically link it with [[ ]] syntax](http://www.onenotegem.com/document/enable-auto-link-creation-by-typing-around-a-phrase-in-onenote).  Is there an equivalent in VSTS-Wiki?

#### OneNote Example

[[I want a new page that is linked]] - when I enter ]']', OneNote creates a new page and links it.  It's an automation process: create a new page and link it.

Comment: [User voice idea](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31878466-create-linked-pages-onenote-style-via)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not supported in VSTS WiKi. You can link a page, but it can’t create a new page if it isn’t existing, it will go to the page with Create Page button, you need to click the Create Page button to create corresponding page.

Format:

```
[text](pagename)
```

Article: [Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/markdown-guidance#links)